# mysql join inside insert into

Tags: mysql, database, join, insert

I have to make a MySQL query, and I´m kind of trapped.

I have three tables: `usuarios`, `combis`, and `usuario_has_combis`.  I make some `SELECT`s to check if a user hasn´t reserved a transport yet.  Up to that point it´s okay.  But I need to query that, if user hasn´t booked a transport yet, to book it, and I have something like this:

```
$insertaPedido = "INSERT INTO usuarios_has_combis (id_usuarios,id_combis,fecha) VALUES ('$user','$combi','$fecha')";
```

The thing is that this combined row is connected with both the `usuarios` table and `combis` table.  I would like to know, where to write the join in this query.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand you, but I think this is what you want:

```
INSERT into usuarios_has_combis (id_usuarios,id_combis,fecha)
SELECT id_usuarios, id_combis, '$fecha'
FROM usuarios, combis
WHERE user = '$user'
AND combi = '$combi'
```

You shouldn't actually interpolate variables into the statement, you should use a prepared statement with placeholders. This just shows the structure.

Comment: well, this actually doesn´t throw an error, but doesn´t insert anything into the database hehehe, don´t know whats going on, but this is the idea. just missing the join parts where `JOIN usuarios AS u ON uhc.id_usuarios = u.id_usuarios JOIN combis AS c ON uhc.id_combis = c.id_combis` i added that and also didn´t work, this is how consult is now.

Comment: You haven't explained clearly what you're trying to do, I was just guessing that you wanted to use these other tables to convert a user name into user ID, and combi name into combi ID. I don't know what you're trying to do by joining with the table you're inserting into, since the row doesn't exist yet. Please clarify the question, ] show some sample data and expected results.

Comment: the smallest example is that theres a table with users, where each user has a unique id, this id is the same id that i use for the usuario_has_combis table, so i need to make a join when inserting in usuarios_has_combis, so it gets the user id, from the users table, i don´t know how much clearer should i be, sorry.

Comment: But how does it know which user ID to get from the users table? What is it joining with?

Comment: the users name, which it gets from another class, one user has one unique id, and if you have the name of the user that´s all you need. then you do the joins and the id will carry the user name and all user data, but, i don´t know where to put the join in the insert.

Comment: That's what my answer does. It expects `$user` is the user's name, `$combi` is the combi name, and `$fecha` is some other data that's being put in the `usuarios_has_combis` table.